# Moq. Mock system class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq

I recieve an old project and start to refactor it for SUT purposes. I use Moq and NUnit framework. I met next class inside this project:

```
public ServerRunner()
{
    Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"];

    WinService = new ServiceController(Name);
    logger = new Logger.Logger(Name);

    syncRoot = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    timeoutMilliseconds = 10000;
}
```

I am new in unit test world so I need advice - how can I extract and mock System.ServiceController class? Can it be done by Moq or I should use some other Mock frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mock ServiceController I'd put it behind an interface. For example,

```
interface IControlServices {
  // ... methods you want to implement
}

class MyServiceController {
  private ServiceController _serviceController;

  public MyServiceController(ServiceController servicecontroller){
    _serviceController = servicecontroller;
  }

  // ... methods you want to implement from interface
}
```

Then use dependency injection (not necessarily with a DI framework) to get it into your ServerRunner class.

Comment: Is it missing the part of the code class MyServiceController : IControlServices ? I didn't understand the relation in between the interface and the concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that `ServiceController` is not an easily `Moq`able class, but you can always do the following:

- Wrap the functionality you need from that class into another custom class (say `ServiceControllerWrapper`).
- Extract the interface (`IServiceControllerWrapper`).
- Pass an `IServiceControllerWrapper` instance to the constructor of `ServerRunner` and use that instance in the class.
- Then you can test the `ServerRunner` class passing a Moq of the `IServiceControllerWrapper` interface as a parameter to the constructor.

It would look like this:

```
public ServerRunner(IServiceControllerWrapper controllerInstance)
{
    Name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceName"];

    WinService = controllerInstance;
    logger = new Logger.Logger(Name);

    syncRoot = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    timeoutMilliseconds = 10000;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Have such own idea, so i will try it